# Bad DMA/do_IRQ errors on suspend/resume, with occasional freezing

Tags: dell, suspend

Every time I suspend or resume my laptop (Dell Latitude E6520, bought this year), I get 2 messages of the form displayed on the console just before shutting down/starting up:

```
[  407.107610] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: dma_pool_free buffer-128, f6f18000/36f18000 (bad dma)
```

On occasion, I get a message of the form:

```
[ 3753.979066] do_IRQ: 0.177 No irq handler for vector (irq -1)
```

On occasion, my machine freezes with a flashing Caps Lock button when suspending, after which I need to do a hard shutdown.  This never happened before the messages started appearing (a while back), and I think it never happens without a do_IRQ message appearing (although I'm not sure about that).  [There's nothing in the owner's manual on a flashing Caps Lock button; apparently it may be a kernel panic if the scroll lock also flashes, but the laptop doesn't have a scroll lock light, and there's no message on the console saying kernel panic.]

Are these bad DMA/do IRQ messages serious, and what can I do to investigate/troubleshoot them and the freezing?

Edit:  I've also now received the following error messages a few times:

```
[246943.023908] JBD: I/O error detected when updating journal superblock for sdb1.
[246943.023958] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 0
[246943.023996] EXT3-fs (sdb1): I/O error while writing superblock
```

Edit: Output of dmesg at http://pastebin.com/ra7MTQEj ; contents of /var/log/kern.log at http://pastebin.com/i6jf0Md9

Edit: the output of some smartctl (-a, -x, --log=error, --log=xerror) instructions is available at http://paste.ubuntu.com/1088488/ .

Edit (31/8/2012): Output of `dmesg|grep -i ehci` available at http://paste.ubuntu.com/1177246/ .

Edit: (3/9/2012):Output of lshw is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/1183032

Comment: **I really don't know**, but I will suggest that you paste the output of the following command: **dmesg | grep -i ehci** to see if there is a hard disk or a usb drive involved. Otherwise **sdb1** has nothing to do with **sda1**. If you check (**fsck**) your root partition (maybe **sda1**) withing you system it seems that you can lost everything. If it is an error of any usb drive maybe the error could be at your **external mouse** or **external keyboard**.

Comment: I am now wondering if the **kern.log** is correctly pasted. Before you paste this file you should reboot your laptop.

Comment: The issues I have are at suspend and resume.  I pasted the `kern.log` after resuming.  Do you want to me reboot and post that `kern.log` as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. "Bad DMA"

Let's deal with the "bad dma" errors first, since they're the only consistent ones which are reflected in your logs.

- These, as well as any problems suspending/resuming, are caused by your internal *USB* 3G modem, which from the MAC address is an Ericsson F3507g.

  - Yes, you read that right. Not every USB device has to be external or plugged into one of the visible USB ports. Modern laptops will run a whole bunch of internal peripherals such as Wireless/3G cards, bluetooth, webcams, etc. from an internal USB "hub".

Notice this tell-tale sequence, which repeats every time the "bad dma" errors occur:

```
[171783.085166] usb 2-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 10
[171783.086623] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: dma_pool_free buffer-128, eafaa000/2afaa000 (bad dma)
[171783.087046] cdc_ncm 2-1.6:1.6: usb0: unregister 'cdc_ncm' usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.6, CDC NCM
[171783.092382] done.
[171783.129959] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: dma_pool_free buffer-128, eb1aa000/2b1aa000 (bad dma)
```

- The `cdc_ncm` module is implicated; this is a [low-level USB interface to high-speed cellular modems](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/USB_NET_CDC_NCM.html)
- This [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/363812) indicates that the F3507g WWAN cards have had similar problems with Ubuntu/Linux before, and a kernel update fixed it.

  - The error should only affect suspend/resume/freezing, and should NOT affect normal operation of the 3G card.
  - But I'd recommend you try one of the mainline kernels (or the Quantal 3.5 kernel), to see if it makes any difference.
  - The other *extreme* alternative, of course, is to either disable your 3G card in the BIOS, or if you actively use it, consider replacing it with another brand/model.

#### 2. "do_IRQ" and "sdb1"

It's harder to debug these isolated warnings without context (which can be the key, as shown above). So we'll just have to guesstimate until you can provide a `kern.log` containing one or both of these errors.

- "do_IRQ" seems to stem most often from PCI-Express bus issues, including graphics cards, and VIA chipsets are often implicated.

  - This message can otherwise be safely ignored.
- Given that your SMART logs look OK, the "sdb1" errors probably come from even more USB communication issues with the external drive.

  - If you find more USB errors around these, I'd chalk it down to an occasional USB incompatibility and not worry; but if they occur only by themselves, it may indicate a problem with the drive. A more complete log would help :)
- Again, I'd recommend trying one of the Quantal 3.5 kernels and seeings if things change, especially for the "do_IRQ".

#### 3. Trying the 3.5-series Quantal Kernel (or a mainline build)

- Once Ubuntu 12.10 is released, its kernel will be made available for 12.04 as a "backport" (the same goes for 13.04 and 13.10).
- Right now, you can get the "beta" kernels from the [Ubuntu-X team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/q-lts-backport/)
- **BUT** this PPA also contains a number of extra packages which you have no need to upgrade.
- So I've made just the backported kernel available in [another PPA](https://launchpad.net/~auanswers/+archive/lts-backported-kernels-prerelease)
- To install:

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:auanswers/lts-backported-kernels-prerelease
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get inst all linux-generic-lts-quantal
  ```
- Reboot, and you should boot into the new kernel (check with `uname -a`). Nvidia/AMD graphics and Broadcom wireless cards may be problematic. You can always select your old 3.2-series kernel by keeping Shift pressed at boot until the Grub menu shows, and then going into "Previous Linux Versions"
- For even more bleeding-edge kernels, you can try one of the mainline builds. Please see this question and answer for more information:

> [Should I upgrade to the "mainline" kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162616/should-i-upgrade-to-the-mainline-kernels)

Comment: FYI: I upgraded from Oneiric to precise to see if that would help as a first step, but no luck.  In fact, I now get other errors from  `watchdog` and `mei` about devices registering a watchdog...  So, I'll try the Quantal kernel next.

Comment: Wait, you're on Oneiric
!?

Comment: I was, but not anymore.

Comment: The Quantal kernel got rid of the bad dma errors, thanks!  How should I proceed in the future? (When/how should I remove the PPA and add the backports?)

Answer (score 2):

The errors you added on the Edit seem to refer to a broken disk sector.

Have you tried running fsck or badblocks?

I suggest you to perform everything from a Live CD environment as follows

1. Boot the live Ubuntu CD (or any other distro)
2. Scan for disks and partitions with fdisk

   ```
   sudo fdisk -l
   ```
3. Once you identified the correct disk label (For example `/dev/sda1`) try running these two commands. The `-c` parameter to the `fsck` command tries to identify and isolate bad blocks

   ```
   sudo e2fsck -cv /dev/sda1
   sudo badblocks -sv /dev/sda
   ```

Comment: Thanks - will follow up on this when I can get a Live CD - hopefully tomorrow.  Meanwhile, it's disappointing to note that neither the `-c` nor the `-v` option of `fsck` appear in its man page. (What does the `-v` do?)

Comment: sorry the program to use was e2fsck not fsck. with e2fsck you can see from the manual that -c is to isolate bad block and -v to be verbose.

Comment: Well, this is all academic, since there is only one hard drive in my machine, and it's /dev/sda, not /dev/sdb.  (In fact, there doesn't seem to be a /dev/sdb on my machine at all.)  However, perhaps /dev/sdb is my external drive that I have plugged in on occasion.  I will try running these tests on that drive.

Comment: I ran e2fsck on /dev/sdb1, output at `http://paste.ubuntu.com/1181414/` - no bad blocks found.

Comment: 1 large file
1 directory ??

This means you have just one file, are you sure you ran the command on the right volume? can you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` ?

Comment: I deleted that part of my comment - sdb1 was an empty partition I had previously used as a bootable Ubuntu.  So the partition was empty before I ran e2fsck, which only added the lost+found directory.

Answer (score 1):

For the "no irq for vector" issue, try adding "pci=nomsi" to the kernel boot options.

Comment: Thanks - this is sporadic, as I say, so I can't say if it will help or not, but I'm trying it