# Why does installing a mainline kernel give me a purple screen?

Tags: kernel

I think it has something to do with the fact that I just installed Kernel 3.5 because it stopped working after this. I can't even get to the login. I don't know how to get into recovery mode or GRUB mode. I'm running Ubuntu desktop as well as Windows 7. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Try pressing `Esc` right after your BIOS loads.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: You should file this bug with `ubuntu-bug linux` so that it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

### The mainline/Quantal kernel doesn't work for you, you need to go back to your old kernel

> Related: [Should I upgrade to the "mainline" kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162616/should-i-upgrade-to-the-mainline-kernels)

- Keep <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed after turning on your computer.
- You will see the Grub menu as shown below. User the down arrow to go to "Previous Linux Versions" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

  [image]
- Select the option which has a version of *x.x.x-generic*, NOT one that has *x.x.x-**yyyyyy**-generic* and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This is usually the first option unless you have installed multiple mainline/custom kernels.

  [image]
- Once successfully booted and logged in, remove the 3.5 kernel with:

  ```
     sudo dpkg -r linux-image-3.5\*
  ```