# a question about kernel updates, ubuntu 12.04

Tags: kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will Ubuntu 12.04.1 include the new Linux kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168218/will-ubuntu-12-04-1-include-the-new-linux-kernel)

It looks like there are more recent kernels than the one I am using.  Synaptic reports my version as 3.2.0.34.37(as my reference)  I read the other day about kernel releases, forgetting to write down the version numbers.  If, in fact, we run behind(Ubuntu) on upgrading our kernel thru the software updater, that would be ok, I just need to get my mind around that.  Further information much appreciated!

---

It appears upon reading further on this, that I could install newer kernels, but that there is some risk involved.  I have, in fact, decided to read more on the subject before proceeding.  For instance, as a fail-safe, I could easily remove the kernel if it didn't suit (nvidia, etc) and go back to using my present kernel.  Maybe more bother than it is worth?   Opinions appreciated on this point as well, of course!

Answer (score 3):

> we run behind(Ubuntu) on upgrading our kernel

Sort of. From Ubuntu repositories you'll be getting only those kernels that have been adjusted to fit the distribution and undergone testing by Ubuntu stuff, not vanilla kernels as available at http://kernel.org.

As can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/FAQ#Kernel.2BAC8-FAQ.2BAC8-GeneralUbuntuDelta.What_differentiates_the_Ubuntu_Kernel_from_the_upstream_Linux_Kernel.3F):

> What differentiates the Ubuntu Kernel from the upstream Linux Kernel?
>
> With every Ubuntu kernel release, we attempt to remain as true to the upstream Linux kernel as possible. However, there are inevitable patches which we carry on top of the upstream Linux kernel which differentiates the Ubuntu kernel from the upstream Linux kernel. This document attempts to describe the general set of patches which are carried and why:
>
> [/Kernel/FAQ/UbuntuDelta](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/FAQ/GeneralUbuntuDelta/Kernel/FAQ/UbuntuDelta)

Moreover, as it can be observed, you'll stay on 3.2.0 unless you upgrade - you'll get updates and backports for this version only.

If you are interested in building your custom kernel - here is a place to start: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile