#  How to upgrade the Linux kernel to version 3.4.7

Tags: installation, kernel, updates

Translation (via Google translate):

Hello, I'm wanting to upgrade the kernel of my Linux version. I'm currently using 3.2.0-27-generic-pae and want to switch to the latest 3.4.7 from the official site.

More information on my computer:

Operating System: Ubuntu

Version: 12.04 (Precise) 32-bit

GNOME: 3.4.1

Memory: 1.8 GiB

Processor: Intel ® Pentium (R) Dual CPU E2220@2.40GHz x 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a good start point: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile/

You may use many other sources on Linux kernel 3.2 (like http://mitchtech.net/compile-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-detailed/) as it's almost the same for Linux kernel 3.4.

Then, if you face any problem, you can search for a solution or come back here and ask about it.

Comment: Obrigado! conseguir solucionar meu problema.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *official* version of kernel 3.4.7 for Ubuntu. The Ubuntu kernel team produces unofficial "mainline" builds for testing purposes only, but for kernels 3.4+, they are doing it for Ubuntu 12.10 (quantal) only.

> **Before proceeding**, please make sure you read and understand the answer to this question:
>   [Should I upgrade to the "mainline" kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162616/should-i-upgrade-to-the-mainline-kernels)

You can get the 3.4.7 mainline kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.4.7-quantal/.

- Install both the generic and the extra packages for your i386 architecture:

  [image]

Comment: Valeu! pela ajuda.