# Intel Wifi isn't working after upgrading to kernel 3.5

Tags: wireless, kernel

After installing kernel upgrade from 3.2 to 3.5 wifi does not work. I have intel wireless. Wireless adapter isn't shown in network settings. How can I enable wifi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a reason the mainline kernels are meant for debugging and testing purposes only. See the below question for more details -- it explicitly warns you may lose wireless:
>
> **[Should I upgrade to the "mainline" kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162616/should-i-upgrade-to-the-mainline-kernels)**

I recommend you go back to the official Ubuntu kernel. The mainline kernels, or kernels you build yourself are not supported and often result in problems with graphics and/or wireless. While the Intel wireless drivers are in-kernel, there is no guarantee they will always work on a non-official kernel.

If you were having problems that *required* you to try upgrading to a mainline kernel, please open a question about that problem and we can try to help you resolve it with the existing kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I had this bug too. Try to find more info about your wifi driver with `modinfo`. In my case is `modinfo brcmsmac`. If that's the case, you can [follow instructions from here](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt) to re compile the driver (isn't that difficult).

Comment: The question says "I have Intel wireless". `brcmsmac` and your link refer to *Broadcom* adapters, not Intel.