# Should i update via software updater after upgrading kernel?

Tags: kernel, update-manager

I have installed too much time ago kernel version 3.12.4-031204-generic from 3.11.0 and it works fine...
However, software-updater gets me updates for kernel 3.11...
Should I get these updates and or just ignore them ?
But accepting these updates would mean me going back to kernel 3.11...
What should I do ?
And is there any way to put software updater get me updates for 3.12.4 ?
I am aware of the dist-upgrade command so please dont't write about it...

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the kernel is the newest version it will be listed first in GRUB's boot list. In Ubuntu the kernel will not be replaced by the new one. So even if the updater brings the 3.13 in your system (reportedly) the 3.12 kernel will still remain.

You have to know that GRUB boot-loader automatically lists the newest kernel first and this depends on the number/version/upload number/ of the kernel.

So 3.11 considered as older than 3.12 and except that will never be replaced, as it is newest it will be listed first in GRUB menu.

Although from the version I can assume that you are using a mainline kernel, [read here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162616/should-i-upgrade-to-the-mainline-kernels) about mainline kernels.

> And is there any way to put software updater get me updates for
>   3.12.4?

As far as I know, no. You must update these unofficial kernels by yourself.

Comment: Thank you NikTh for you answered all my quaries...But I have another one quary...Do you suggest me dropping this mainline kernel that I was using and return to using the 3.11 ?

Comment: Θα μπορούσαμε και να μιλάμε στα ελληνικά αλλά καλά κάνεις μήπως είχε την ίδια απορία και κάποιος άλλος και γενικότερα πολύ καλά κάνεις που βοηθάς έτσι να εδραιωθεί το Ubuntu, και γενικότερα τα Linux/Unix συστήματα, στην Ελλάδα και επιτέλους να μάθουν και κάτι άλλο (που είναι και καλύτερο εν τέλει) από τα Windows και την Microsoft...Σ'ευχαριστώ πολύ

Comment: Thank you NikTh...I returned to my 3.11...Your help was enlightening!...

Comment: For Greek language at the moment we can use the [Greek Ubuntu forums](https://forum.ubuntu-gr.org/). In the future I hope [this blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/community-1305-q+a-systems-localization) it will take shape. :-)