# XPS 13 (9350), failure to resume: wasn't this fixed?

Tags: 14.04, suspend, dell, xps

My brand new XPS 13 (9350) is experiencing what looks like [this bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638835/xps-13-9343-failure-to-resume-from-suspend). Based on what I've read, it seems the fix for that bug was incorporated into the Ubuntu kernel months ago. How do I deal with a bug that's not supposed to exist anymore?

I don't want to try installing Dell's [patch](http://www.dell.com/support/article/ca/en/cabsdt1/SLN297551/en), because:

1. I'm nervous about installing something directly from a file, rather than through a package manager.
2. The package description says it's a backport from kernel 3.19 to 3.13, and I'm already running 3.19.

Kernel version, copied from `uname -a` output:

`3.19.0-33-generic #38~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: That patch was released for the Wily kernel, which is 15.10. You seem to be on 14.04. The fix is most likely in kernel 4.4, but not in 3.19. You should either upgrade to 16.04 or upgrade the kernel.

Comment: @Zacharee1, that sounds reasonable. Being able to suspend might be worth more to me than the assurance of stability that comes from being on LTS, so maybe I'll try upgrading to 16.04. I've seen a report of a similar problem on 16.04 (http://askubuntu.com/questions/771240/suspend-broken-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-dell-xps-9350), although this comment (http://askubuntu.com/questions/771240/suspend-broken-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-dell-xps-9350#comment1165257_771240) suggests it's fixed now.

Comment: 16.04 is LTS. Every two years.

Comment: @Zacharee1—oops, I noticed that just after I commented. The upgrade to 16.04 seems to have fixed the issue! If you post your comment as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.