# Updating to Kernel 4.6 on 16.04

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 16.04

I have a fairly fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 running on Kernel 4.4.0-22.

Today I saw that the latest stable kernel version is 4.6 on kernel.org and I have a few questions:

> 1. Is it worth upgrading to this version of the kernel?
> 2. Is it safe to do this with Ubuntu 16.04?
> 3. Is there a not-extremely-complicated way to upgrade your kernel?

My specs are: i7-6500U, 8GB RAM DDR3, 128GB SSD, Radeon R7 M360 4GB

Comment: It is not supported, and there is no need to do it.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/162616/should-i-upgrade-to-the-mainline-kernels

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1) Unless there's something that's been added in 4.5 or 4.6 that you really need and it hasn't already been backported to 4.4 in Ubuntu, then not really.

2) Highly likely yes.  Even if 4.6 does fail to boot for whatever reason, you could always boot back into 4.4 then get rid of 4.6.

3) There's a very easy way: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/install-linux-kernel-4-6-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: This:  _Various open-source AMD graphics driver improvements_ feature is the main reason I'd like to upgrade. My Radeon R7 M300 is giving me a lot of trouble.

Comment: @ValeriuA.Cuc, are you aiming for `AMDGPU` driver or `radeon` ? My card is `Radeon HD 7730M`