# Tried to update Kernel, broke Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 12.04, kernel, software-center

Ubuntu 12.04 here.
So, I tried to update my Kernel, which I did succeed in the end, but I did a way of updating it a bit... well, wrong.
So... Ubuntu Software-Center is now not functional and when I run it's command through the command line, this is the last error line:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'`
Now I know that the Kernel update did this from other commands rendering out stuff like "*linux-image-generic-4.1100... line in /var/etc/apt/* **?** " when I was trying to fix the issue.

I don't know much about these sorts of errors/issues/broken stuff but I think I need to delete those Kernel `.deb` files.

Anyway, I'm used to messing stuff up like this, however thanks in advance if you have an answer!

Aha! This is a system error that I got: `The package linux-image-4.11.0-041100rc5-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.` I need to uninstall that

Here is what I followed... and, uh, I guess it was unstable, I wanted to get the latest verison, but didn't know. This is it -> [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/a/885165/611459)

Comment: Aha! This is a system error that I got:  " The package linux-image-4.11.0-041100rc5-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it. " I need to uninstall that

Comment: Please put all the updates in your question not in comments. How did you try to update kernel? As far as I know, the latest stable linux kernel is 4.10.8. And that is also not recommended to be installed on Ubuntu for stability. You tried to install unstable kernel on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Ok. Here is what I followed... and, uh, I guess it was unstable, I wanted to get the latest verison, but didn't know. This is it -> http://askubuntu.com/a/885165/611459

Comment: I don't know why you need the latest kernel. If you really need, go for installation again but do not remove it. see if your system works fine, then remove it.

Comment: Alright. Just, where can I get the latest and greatest STABLE verison? And tutorial

Comment: Go through the same procedure you went. Notice the error you get: `The package linux-image-4.11.0-041100rc5-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.` That is happening because you removed the deb file after installation. do it again. But I think you should consider going back to your original kernel

Comment: Done. Re-did it all and the Software Center is swell and working. Although, my System Monitor says I still have the 3.8.0 kernel. Well, it's all good and... I needed to update the kernel for another issue I had- which is now fixed!  Whew! Thank you, good sir. It may now be closed. And one more thing, when I "installed" the deb packages, I got this error in the terminal: "Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.11.0-041100rc5-generic." However, I am all good now, thank you.

Comment: I mean click on tick icon in left side of the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, You have tried to update your kernel to the latest mainline kernel which is not a good idea ([ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/162617/214264)). But still if you need (for some reason like hardware compatibility or anything else) to do so this is the way:

In the [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/885165/611459) you shared as your workflow you have removed the the deb file related to new kernel right after installation. That is why you get the error `The package linux-image-4.11.0-041100rc5-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it`. Logically everything should go fine and you shouldn't get this error if the installation was done well. But it seems there has been some problem and there was a need for reinstallation.

Now, go through the same procedure and download and install the kernel but this time don't remove the deb file.

Reboot your system. If you don't get the error, now you can remove the deb file.