# How to upgrade my ubuntu 14.04 linux kernel 4.4 to linux kernel 4.12

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel

When I ran the librealsense examples the error require to upgrade the Linux kernel to 4.12:

```
root@ubuntu:~/librealsense/build# ./examples/save-to-disk/rs-save-to-disk
RealSense error calling rs2_pipeline_start(pipe:0x1cd7c10):
    Requested pixel format is not natively supported by the Linux kernel and likely requires a patch for fourcc code INZI!
Alternatively please upgrade to kernel 4.12 or later. Last Error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I tried to upgrade the Linux kernel but failed.
Could anyone tell me the detail operations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not supported in that old distribution, you could use the latest using the mainline kernels as described here:

[Should I upgrade to the "mainline" kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162616/should-i-upgrade-to-the-mainline-kernels)

Unfortunately it looks like the Xenial kernel is the latest supported on 14.04 and it looks like there is no point release in the near future:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule