# Wireless device Intel Corporation Device 9df0 (rev 30) DISABLED on 18.04.3

Tags: wireless, network-manager, internet, asus, iwlwifi

I'm new to Ubuntu. I will try to provide as much detail as possible in this question, but if I have left anything out, please let me know in the comments and I will provide it. If this question would be better in a different forum, please let me know which forum.

My wireless interface was working until 3 days ago when I believe an update I said OK to disabled it. When I do `sudo lshw -C network`, I get:

```
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 30
       serial: 00:bb:60:08:95:85
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.1.0-050100-generic firmware=46.6bf1df06.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:b431c000-b431ffff
```

When I do `iwlist scan`, I get:

```
wlo1      Failed to read scan data : Network is down
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning
```

When I do `sudo service network-manager restart` and then `sudo service network-manager status`, I get this error in the output (abbreviated here):

```
<error> [1576682510.9833] sup-iface[0x5655383f5240,wlo1]: error adding interface: wpa_supplicant couldn't grab this interface.
```

Finally, when I do `rfkill list all`, I get:

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Those are the main things I've looked at.

I've rebooted my computer a few times, restarted network-manager, and tried to do `ip set wlo1 up` and `ifconfig set wlo1 up` (this latter command is outdated for me and so doesn't work).

Now for my system info: I have an ASUS Zenbook and am dual-booting Ubuntu `18.04.3 LTS`. I am using my phone in the meantime as an ethernet connection. When I run `lsusb`, I get:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:56cb IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 062a:4101 Creative Labs Wireless Keyboard/Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c76:161e JMTek, LLC. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When I run `lspci`, I get:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e34 (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df9 (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9ded (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 9def (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df0 (rev 30)
00:14.5 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df5 (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9de8 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9de9 (rev 30)
00:15.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9deb (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9de0 (rev 30)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9dc5 (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db8 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9dbc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d84 (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9dc8 (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9da3 (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9da4 (rev 30)
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5003 (rev 01)
```

If I have left out any useful information, please let me know.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: You are using an unsupported mainline kernel. I would suggest to use `linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge` Ubuntu 5.3 kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6, changing my kernel worked. Thanks very much! I was wondering if I could trouble you a little more about how I can use `linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge`. I changed kernels by using the ukuu GUI and installing the Linux 5.3 option. When I do `uname -r` in terminal, I get `5.3.0-050300-generic` out. This is a mainline version from what I understand since it has the format ` x.x.x-yyyyyy-generic` as detailed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162616/should-i-upgrade-to-the-mainline-kernels.
From what I understand, all kernels from ukuu are mainline.

Comment: My question is, how do I change to `linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge` using ukuu? Or even how do I change to it some other way?

Comment: It is not done by UKUU. UKUU is not a normal way of Ubuntu kernel installation. You install it by `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! 

Again, feel free to leave your comment as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an unsupported mainline kernel.

I suggest to install the 5.3 HWE Ubuntu kernel.

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge
```

and reboot.